# NODE_ENV production alternative name

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express.js app for which the production environment name is `foo`. So I start my app like `NODE_ENV=foo node app.js`. **In general this is a bad idea**.

Now my app knows it is in production, but Express doesn't know. Regardless of whether this is a good idea or not in general, is there a way to tell Express that it's running in production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misusing the `NODE_ENV` setting. If you would set the value to `production`, ie. you're running Node in production enviroment (that you happen to call `foo`), [Express would read it automatically](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table).

You can use `app.set('env', 'production');` to set the mode if you really must use `NODE_ENV` for other purposes. Then you would need a way to tell your app if it is in production mode, eg.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'foo') {
  app.set('env', 'production');
}
```

or introduce another environment variable and use its value: `app.set('env', process.env.REAL_NODE_ENV);` and then run with `NODE_ENV=foo REAL_NODE_ENV=production node app.js`

I would still suggest to use another environment variable than `NODE_ENV` to tell your app it's running on `foo`.